# jquery datatable excel export button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi i'm using Datatables js version `1.9.4` css version `1.9.4`. And initialize the data table using below code.

Also added support js and css

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/excel-export/dataTables.buttons.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/excel-export/buttons.flash.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/excel-export/jszip.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/excel-export/buttons.html5.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/excel-export/buttons.print.min.js}"></script>
<link th:href="@{/resources/js/excel-export/buttons.dataTables.min.css}"
    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

var tblUnSubscribedKeys = $('#tblUnSubscribedKeys').DataTable({
                     "aoColumns" : [ null, null,null,null,null,null],
                     "processing": true,
                     "serverSide": true,
                     dom: 'Bfrtip',
                           buttons: [
                               'excel'
                           ]
                 });
```

The problem is, the data on the table populated correctly. But the excel export button is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the buttons configuration for [datatables 1.10](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons)

It's a little different in [Datatables 1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html)

Here's a bit of code I've used in the past to show CSV buttons:

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
            "aButtons" : [
                {
                    "sExtends" : "csv",
                    "sButtonText" : "Download Excel"
                },
                {
                    "sExtends" : "pdf",
                    "sButtonText" : "Download PDF",
                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape"
                }
            ],
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
```

That worked for me, but you should check the docs and adapt it as you see fit.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Check that you have downloaded the buttons plugin: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/

Here's the 1.9.x tabletools docs: http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/alter_buttons.html

Comment: i double check the button plugin.

Comment: Hey i updated datatable 10 from their site and paste to html page and its works..But when i used the same code in my web app it not even showing the buttons.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me. Add this cdn css and js in your page.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">



  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```